# All final variables must be initialized, but '' isn't. Try adding an initializer for the field.dartfinal_not_initialized_constructor

Tags: flutter, dart

I just need to pass an attribute to a constructor `AppTheme`, but i received an error:

***All final variables must be initialized, but '' isn't.
Try adding an initializer for the field.dartfinal_not_initialized_constructor***

**the code is:**

```
class AppTheme extends StatelessWidget {
  const AppTheme({required this.navigator}); // => Cursor error 
  final  Widget navigator,
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    throw UnimplementedError();
  }}
```

Comment: I think your `,` needs to be a `;` - `final  Widget navigator;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class AppTheme extends StatelessWidget {
  const AppTheme({required this.navigator}); 
  final  Widget navigator; // from , to ;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    throw UnimplementedError();
  }}
```